# How to dynamically create where clauses given a list of parameters?

Tags: python, peewee

Would it be possible to dynamically add filters to a Peewee select statement given a list? For example instead of:

```
Table.select().paginate(page,ENTRY_PER_PAGE).where((Table.Base==Base1) & (Table.Base==Base2) & ...)
```

I would like to pass in, say a `list`, and it would filter by content in that `list`:

```
list = [Base1, Base2, Base3...]
Table.select().paginate(page,ENTRY_PER_PAGE).where((Table.Base==contentfromList))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) ([`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#reduce) in Python 3.x):

```
>>> import operator
>>> reduce(operator.mul, [2, 3, 5])
30
>>> 2 * 3 * 5
30
```

With generator expression:

```
base_list = [Base1, Base2, Base3]
Table.select().paginate(page,ENTRY_PER_PAGE).where(
    reduce(oeprator.and_, (Table.Base == b for b in base_list))
)
```

Instead of `operator.and_` (`operator.__and__`), if you need to express more complex expression, you can also use [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
...
reduce(lambda a, b: a & b, (Table.Base == b for b in base_list))
...
```

Comment: Ah, that's great! Question though, what exactly does the "_" in operator.and_ do? Any reason why we can't simply use && or || ?

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat, If you mean `(... for .. in ...)`, it's a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions).

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat, There's no `&&`, `||` operator in Python, but `and`, `or`.

Comment: oh, and one last question @falsetru, for your last example, you have a,b, where does the a come from?

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat, `lambda` expression is a kind of expression that returns a function. Please follow the link in the answer. (to links to `reduce`, `lambda`)